# How do I set a variable in a CakePHP model and access it in a view?

Tags: cakephp

I have multiple models that I want to add the variable `$section` to, and then use that value in `sidenav.ctp` to dynamically change the sidebar.  For example, my models are:

```
class Resource extends AppModel {
    public $section = 'section1';
    public $displayField = 'name';
    public $order = 'modified DESC';

    //validation, relationships, etc.
}
```

then I have another model like:

```
class Topic extends AppModel {
    public $section = 'section2';
    public $tablePrefix = '';

    //validation, relationships, etc.
}
```

so in `sidenav.ctp` I want to do something like:

```
<?php if ($this->section == 'section1') { ?>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Resources'), array('controller' => 'resources', 'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Topics'), array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Log Out'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); ?> </li>
<?php } ?>

<?php if ($this->section == 'section2') { ?>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Resources1'), array('controller' => 'resources', 'action' => 'index')); ?></li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Topics1'), array('controller' => 'topics', 'action' => 'index')); ?> </li>
    <li><?php echo $this->Html->link(__('Log Out1'), array('controller' => 'users', 'action' => 'logout')); ?> </li>
<?php } ?>
```

but accessing `$section` this way doesn't work.  I can't figure out how to set the value in the Model and then access it in the View.  I'm aware that I could set the value in the Controller and then access it just by `$section`, but that would require me putting it in every function.

Comment: Why in the model? I think is not necessary.

Comment: If I were to put it in the controller, how would I set it so I wouldn't need to put it in each function individually?

Comment: You would show different menu for different models ?

Comment: Yes, that's what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try in your view file `$this->name == 'ModelName'`

like this example:

```
<li <?php if($this->name == 'Users'){?> class="active" <?php } ?> >
            <a href="<?php echo $this -> Html -> url(array('plugin' => false, 'controller' => 'pages', 'action' => 'dashboard')); ?>">
                <i class="fa fa-dashboard"></i>
                <span><?php echo __('Dashboard', true); ?></span>
                <span class="label label-warning pull-right">1</span>
            </a>
        </li>
```

OR

in your controllers beforeFilter or beforeRender methods:

```
//access variable from  model
$this->set('sections',$this->User->section);

//or set direct     
$this->set('sections','section1');
```

Comment: `$this->name` will give me the name of the model itself, but I'm trying to set a custom variable in each model so I can access them in the view.

Comment: Yes it gives you the name of the model. You can use it as I have shown. But since you insist on using its own variables, I edited and added these features in my answer.

Comment: I get that I could do something like `if ($model == 'Model1' || $model == 'Model2' || $model == 'Model3') { /*show menu1*/ } else  if ($model == 'Model4') { /*show menu2*/ }`, but I want to be able to define which `section` each Model belongs to, rather having to put these long conditionals anywhere I want to have this functionality.

Comment: I ended up using `beforeFilter` in each controller to set the variable.  This gives me the same functionality as if it were set in the model.  Plus, in MVC the model and the view shouldn't communicate directly, so the controller is the correct spot to put this anyway.

Answer (score 0):

View's / Elements can be called and rendered by any controller, so they won't automatically know what data you want it to refer to unless you pass it from the model to the view. 
The nearest you can do which isn't of any use would be to echo the Router model methods, but the results are dependent on the url you are at.

Comment: "unless you pass it from the model to the view" - that's what I'm trying to do.  My best effort so far is using `beforeFilter` in the controller and setting the variable there.

Answer (score 0):

you can save define **global** variables

```
Configure::write('my_var','this is model variable');
```

and **access this variable** in your view file like this

```
echo Configure::read('my_var');
```